How to display total lazy plugins loaded in statusline
As the title suggest I try to display the total of loaded lazy plugins in the statusline. I tried to use the function stats from the stats.lua file without success.

I'm not sure did i understand correctly but here is how to show plugin number in status line or with lualine.
Read lazy-lock.json. File where lazy stores data about plugins.
local function plugin_num()
  local count = 0

  local path = vim.fn.stdpath("config") .. "/lazy-lock.json"

  local file = io.open(path, "r")

  if not file then
    print("File not found")
  else
    local content = file:read("a")

    local status, json = pcall(vim.fn.json_decode, content)

    if status then
      for _, _ in pairs(json) do
        count = count + 1
      end
    else
      print("failed decoding json")
    end
    file:close()
    return count
  end
end

Show it on status line
vim.cmd("set statusline+="  .. plugin_num())

Show it using lualine
   sections = {
     lualine_x = { plugin_num }
   },

